Jasper Studio CE source code no more available
I'm looking for Jasper Studio CE source code or, if available, to a fork of the last open source version of Jasper Studio CE.
Anyone have the last open source versione and can share the link to the source code?
Is there a fork starting from the last open source version?
I'v found on JasperSoft forum that starting by february the software is free but no more open source: https://community.jaspersoft.com/forums/topic/68130-where-is-jaspersoft-studio-ce-repository/#comment-161862

JasperStudio installers can be found at https://github.com/neuralnexus/OpenJasper. Source code not available. Yet.
